# iOS Enable Rotation for all Orientations iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I've written a tabbed application with a few view controllers, and on iOS 6 it rotates happily in all orientations as I've got them all supported in the app summary.

My deployment target however is iOS 5 and I'd like to be able to rotate in all orientations on this too. I've tried varies combinations of:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape;
}
```

But none are enabling rotation for iOS 5. Do I need to put this method in just the app delegate or in all the view controllers? Am I doing it totally wrong??

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this all your view controllers

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

or you can edit your plist's `Supported Interface orientations`

Comment: That's already in my plist, but I'll try adding that to all the view controllers.

Comment: I had to use `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}`

Comment: that is strange it should've worked, anyway if your solution worked for you thats great

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 5.0, also add to your view controller, and you can also change it in your build settings, and your info plist file, to be sure.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES;
}
```

Comment: hmmm, essentially it's the same thing regardless. It's a boolean and returns yes for all values. But as long as listing all of them work fine, then more power to you, bro!

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Worked great